# Excel 2013 Date Grouping - Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2013, once i group my date column by Year,Months,Days it is converting the date value to a string which results in it sorting out of order.  I have already double checked that the values are in fact an integer prior to grouping by using 'CTRL + ~'.  How can I get the "Days" section to stay as integer so it orders properly? Example below.
[image: Pivot Table Date Grouping]

Comment: Hello @pnuts - Within a pivot table under field settings, that's correct.

Comment: This is a 64 bit system.

Comment: Well hopefully further commentary will disprove that, I see no reason for this to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware that existed.  I have flagged the post and requested the move.

Answer (score -1):

From the small portion of data that I see, it appears that your pivot table is sorted by the sum of "REV" rather than the date.

Comment: Considering that the entire point of the question is that the dates are being sorted out of order, I'd say that it makes a big difference.